# Swap and escaped character for an escaped character

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
<p><span style=\"font-family: Verdana;\">Test<br/></span></p>
```

`templateString = templateString.Replace('\"', '\'');`

Produces..... without character escaping.

```
<p><span style='font-family: Verdana;'>Test<br/></span></p>
```

Where the `'` is not escaped, which throws errors later on.

Other attempts....... one of many....

`templateString = templateString.Replace(@"""", @"\'");`

```
<p><span style=\\'font-family: Verdana;\\'>Test<br/></span></p>
```

Does anyone have a solution that works?

What i want, is that when i hover over the value for `templateString` after the replace operation, it should hold the value of.....

```
<p><span style=\'font-family: Verdana;\'>Test<br/></span></p>
```

Anyone?

More attempts....

`templateString = templateString.Replace("\"", @"\'");`

```
<p><span style=\\'font-family: Verdana;\\'>Test<br/></span></p>
```

`templateString = templateString.Replace("\"", "\'");`

```
<p><span style='font-family: Verdana;'>Test<br/></span></p>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not displaying the single backslash because C# uses double quotes for strings? I mean, you will see `'` for a single quote instead of `\"` because if C# didn't use double quotes for strings, it would appear as `"` instead. So if you try to put a \ , you end up with `\\'` to escape the backslash and not the quote. `\'` would appear as `'` anyway. That's how I see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

`\\\"` and replace with `'`

Here is a demo:

http://regex101.com/r/xC5fM7

Comment: this is not regex. It is c#. It won't work the way it works in javascript

Comment: Yeah man. Using C# here. Format will be templateString.replace("\"","\'");

Comment: templateString = templateString.Replace("\\\"",@"\'");  this doesn't work. It doesn't replace anything and the string is returned as it was when it went into the function.